# Getting Error with Django Phone Number Form Field

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm building a Django form that includes a phone number field.  I've been referring to these two SO questions to understand how to do it: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130942/whats-the-best-way-to-store-phone-number-in-django-models), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478875/regular-expression-matching-e-164-formatted-phone-numbers).  I've created this form field:

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    phone = forms.RegexField(
        regex = r'^\+?[1-9]\d{1,14}$',
        #regex = r'\+?\d{10,14}$',
        error_messages = {'required', 'Phone number required'},
        widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
    )
```

I display the field in my template:

```
<div>
    <label for="id_phone">Your Phone Number</label>
    {{ form.phone.errors }}
    {{ form.phone }}
</div>
```

I understand what the regexes are doing and they look correct to me.  However, I'm getting this error if I use either one of them:

```
ValueError at /business/contact/
dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 8; 2 is required
...
Exception Location: /srv/http/example.com/venvs/dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/fields.py in __init__, line 125
(stacktrace...)
widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
super(RegexField, self).__init__(max_length, min_length, *args, **kwargs)
super(CharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
messages.update(error_messages or {})
(end of stacktrace)
```

Can anyone see what's causing this error?  It seems to be caused by the regexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just discovered the error.  It's in this line:

```
error_messages = {'required', 'Phone number required'},
```

I needed to replace the "," with a ":":

```
error_messages = {'required': 'Phone number required'},
```