# Validating International Phone Numbers in PHP

Tags: php, regex, forms, validation

I've been searching for hours to find a regex that does this for me, all the ones I've found either require dashes or limit something else that I don't need.

Like this one: 
    ^(?([0-9]{3}))?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$

Basically I want to allow these types of input for phone number, these are all valid:

+000 111111111

+00011111111111

0022 111111111111

0022111111111

+333-4444-5555-6666

000-7878787-0000-4587

Note that the number of digits is not limited, I only want the validation to filter out empty inputs and the alphabet. Also filter out all other characters except a maximum of 4 dashes, max. 4 spaces and an optional single plus sign.

Is this possible through preg_match or not?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113908/what-regular-expression-will-match-valid-international-phone-numbers

Comment: $numSpaces = preg_match_all('/[ ]/', $phone, $matches);
$numDashes = preg_match_all('/[-]/', $phone, $matches);
$numPlus = preg_match_all('/[+]/', $phone, $matches);
 

if (!empty ($phone) && (is_numeric($phone))) {
if (($numSpaces <= 4) && ($numDashes <= 4) &&  ($numPlus <= 1)) {
$validphone = true;
}
}
else {
$validphone = false;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strip wanted characters out (" ", "-"), count the amount then chuck an if statement if count <= 4 (for the "+" character it would be == 1). So in total it would be

if (countSpace <= 4 && countDash <= 4 && countPlus == 1) {
...
}

As for being empty, just use the standard form validation for checking if the input has been filled or not.

Comment: Thanks so much! This actually helped me find a way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Sure its possible. But to my opinion dangerous to use stuff that is not understood. I would do something like this

```
^(?!(?:\d*-){5,})(?!(?:\d* ){5,})\+?[\d- ]+$
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2u98l)

The last part `\+?[\d- ]+` allows an optional `+` followed by at least one digit, dash or space

The negative lookaheads ensure that there are not more than 4 dash or spaces.

Limitations:
- The dash or space can be in one row
- it accepts also `-` as valid

Try it yourself on the Regexr link, you can just add examples what you want.

Comment: Before seeing your answer, using James's advice, I did this:

Comment: $numSpaces = preg_match_all('/[ ]/', $phone, $matches);
$numDashes = preg_match_all('/[-]/', $phone, $matches);
$numPlus = preg_match_all('/[+]/', $phone, $matches);

if (!empty ($phone) && (is_numeric($phone))) {
if (($numSpaces <= 4) && ($numDashes <= 4) &&  ($numPlus <= 1)) {
$validphone = true;
}
}
else {
$validphone = false;
}