# Regex digits with length and some specific characters

Tags: regex, angularjs-ng-pattern

I have a phone number input field where it must:

1. Allows spaces and "-" and "+" characters.
2. Have 12 characters max including the special characters (ex +12345678910).

I tried but my best result was `ng-pattern="/^\+?\d{0,11}?$/"`.
How to make this work?

Comment: It is not clear what your requirements are. Please add some examples that you need to match.

Comment: @Wiktor: what's not clear?

Comment: It's not clear if the length of characters/digits includes the extra "characters" you mention, etc. Show an example of what you expect...

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: Try `ng-pattern="/^(?!.{13})\+?\d[-\d]*$/"`. Sorry, given the current requirements, it is going to be a guessing game.

Comment: `^[\s0-9+-]{1,13}$`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're trying to match a phone number? Maybe this is helpful: [What regular expression will match valid international phone numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113908/what-regular-expression-will-match-valid-international-phone-numbers)

Otherwise, if no particular order or restrictions for your numbers, `+`, `-` or spaces, this should do the work: `/^[0-9\+\-\s]{1,12}$/`

https://regex101.com/r/kuc5OF/2

Comment: Thanks for the answer but how to limit the length to 12 characters?

Comment: Do you want to limit the length of ALL the characters, including the special ones `+`, `-` and spaces? That would be the `{1,12}` part.

Comment: Yeah including the special ones. I edited my question. This doesn't seem to work --> [Test](https://regex101.com/r/kuc5OF/1/)

Comment: `^/[0-9\+\-\s]{1,12}/$` - you need to specify the start `^` and end `$` modifiers for an exact match. I updated my answer.

Comment: You're welcome! As long as it worked, no time was wasted.