# phone number field is not validating

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new in codeigniter please help me to find the error!!!! my mobile number field is not validating incodeigniter.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('mobilenumber', 'Mobile Number', 'required|regex_match[/(7|8|9)\d{9}/]');
```

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16699507/1219741

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('mobile', 'Mobile Number ', 'required|regex_match[/^[0-9]{10}$/]');
```

{10} for 10 digits number
use this one hope it will work for you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113908/what-regular-expression-will-match-valid-international-phone-numbers                                                or you can try this one..